# How do you have a user input values in an array using a function in C++?

Tags: c++, function, multidimensional-array, user-input

Ok so I have this code to have users input numbers into an array but would like to make it into a function. I am new to C++ and am unsure how to go about it. Can anyone give me some hints or tips? I would greatly appreciate it. The code is as follows:

```
main()
{
 int m;
 int n;
 int i;
 int j;
 int A[100][100];

 m = get_input ();
 n = get_input2 (); 

 cout << endl << "Enter positive integers for the elements of matrix A:" << endl;

 for (i = 0 ; i < m ; i++)
     for (j = 0 ; j < n ; j++)
         cin >> A[i][j];
return;
}
```

Comment: The main point is you'll need to `new` the memory for the array, not define it on the stack, then free it afterwards. Pass in the dimensions, return the `new`ed data, then call `delete[]` on it when you're done. (Unless you want to also pass in the allocated array? In which case you can use local variables for that too.)

Comment: Does it have to be an array specifically? In C++, the idiomatic way to do this would be to use a std::vector. What do you intend to do with the array after? Do you need to do anything other than access elements by [] []? It's usually better to avoid delete in C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void initialize(int x[][], int m, int n){
    cout << endl << "Enter positive integers for the elements of matrix A:" << endl;

    for (int i = 0 ; i < m ; i++)
       for (int j = 0 ; j < n ; j++)
       cin >> x[i][j];
}

main()
{
    int A[100][100],m,n;

   // m = get_input ();// you must have that method or cin>>m
    //n = get_input2 (); //you must have that method or cin>>n
     cout<<"Enter no of rows";
     cin>>m;
     cout<<"Enter no of columns";
     cin>>n;
    initialize (A,m,n);
    return;
 }
```